# Is there a maximum character length for a document.id (auto-generated) in firestore python google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

We are using Firestore for our database. Is there a maximum character length for the auto generated document-id ? I cannot seem to find the answer in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) anywhere.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#limits) says that the limit for all document IDs is 1500 bytes.

Comment: How much characters?

Comment: I believe it depends on the characters you use, since the coding is UTF-8.  It's at least 375 characters.

Comment: Just use an online tool like https://mothereff.in/byte-counter to count how many bytes there is in your string. If your string is made up of only UTF-8 letters ( aA to zZ ) and numbers ( 0 to 9 ) then each characters is exactly one byte.